# Как изменить отступ в Drawer menu

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer

Мне нужно изменить отступ между иконкой и текстом. Так вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058219/how-to-programatically-set-the-margin-between-icon-and-title-of-menu-item-of-nav) говорят что невозможно. Вопрос: а может есть все таки способ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хороший вопрос! Я не нашел ответа. Поверил, что нельзя.

Comment: ну а если пробелов наставить, типа "   Имя", "   Лицевой счет"... он их с-trim-ит?)

Comment: Не знаю.) Но мне наоборот нужно было уменьшить отступ...

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению нельзя такое сделать, используя стандартный NavigationView, т.к. там уже заложены такие стандарты. Только если делать свое меню.